# Pgfmath numerical quaternion multiplication for 3D rotation

Tags: pgfmath

I need to rotate coordinates in a 3D space by a certain known angle around a given axis, in order to draw solids in tikz.
One way to do this is to calculate the product **p q p<sup>-1</sup>**, where **p** is a quaternion defined as [image: Definition of Rotation Quaterion], and **q** is the point you want to rotate: [image].
In the case of rotations we can obtain **p<sup>-1</sup>** simply by flipping the sign of the imaginary part of p, i.e. [image]

The product is calculated by the macro

```
\newcommand{\quaternionproduct}[2] {
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[0] - {#1}[1]*{#2}[1] - {#1}[2]*{#2}[2] - {#1}[3]*{#2}[3]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[1] + {#1}[1]*{#2}[0] + {#1}[2]*{#2}[3] - {#1}[3]*{#2}[2]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[2] - {#1}[1]*{#2}[3] + {#1}[2]*{#2}[0] + {#1}[3]*{#2}[1]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[3] + {#1}[1]*{#2}[2] - {#1}[2]*{#2}[1] + {#1}[3]*{#2}[0]}\pgfmathresult
}
```

which should return another quaternion according to the product rules (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product), and it does:

```
\def\angle{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{cos(\angle/2)     }
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{sin(\angle/2)* 2/7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{sin(\angle/2)* 3/7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{sin(\angle/2)* 6/7}
\def\myquatP {\r, \x, \y, \z} % Rotates 30° about the unit vector (2/7, 3/7, 6/7)
\def\myquatInvP{\r, -\x, -\y, -\z} % = P^-1

\def\myquatQ{\quaternionfromxyz{1, 1, 1}} % A point to rotate
\def\myquatTmp{\quaternionproduct{\myquatP}{\myquatQ}}\myquatTmp % This prints the correct result
```

However, when I go ahead in the calculation, if I try to reuse the newly calculated result, the compilation fails with the error  `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 38`.

```
 \def\myquatQrot{\quaternionproduct{\myquatTmp}{\myquatInvP}}\myquatQrot % Not working
```

How do I generate rotated coordinates to use in tikz?
I wish I could do something like:

```
\newcommand{\rotate}[2]{
    \quaterniontoxyz{
        \quaternionproduct{
            #1 % First argument is P, the rotation
         }{
           \quaternionproduct{ % This is a nested products
              \quaternionfromxyz(#2)
           }{
              \quaternioninvert{#1} % Inverts P
           }
         }
     } % Conversion to x,y,z
 } % End newcommand

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[] (\rotate{\myquatP}{1, 1, 1}) -- (\rotate{\myquatP}{0, 0, 0});
  % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\quaternionfromxyz}[1] {0, #1}
\newcommand{\quaterniontoxyz}[1] {
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[1]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[2]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[3]}\pgfmathresult}

\newcommand{\quaternionproduct}[2] {
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[0] - {#1}[1]*{#2}[1] - {#1}[2]*{#2}[2] - {#1}[3]*{#2}[3]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[1] + {#1}[1]*{#2}[0] + {#1}[2]*{#2}[3] - {#1}[3]*{#2}[2]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[2] - {#1}[1]*{#2}[3] + {#1}[2]*{#2}[0] + {#1}[3]*{#2}[1]}\pgfmathresult,
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]*{#2}[3] + {#1}[1]*{#2}[2] - {#1}[2]*{#2}[1] + {#1}[3]*{#2}[0]}\pgfmathresult
}

\begin{document}
    \def\angle{30}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{cos(\angle/2)     }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{sin(\angle/2)* 2/7}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{sin(\angle/2)* 3/7}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{sin(\angle/2)* 6/7}
    \def\myquatP {\r, \x, \y, \z} % Rotates 30° about the unit vector (2/7, 3/7, 6/7)
    \def\myquatInvP{\r, -\x, -\y, -\z} % = P^-1

    \myquatP

    \myquatInvP

    % A test to check whether the product function works (and it does)
    \quaternionproduct{\myquatP}{\myquatInvP} % This should be (1, 0, 0, 0)

    \def\myquatQ{\quaternionfromxyz{1, 1, 1}} % A point to rotate
    \def\myquatTmp{\quaternionproduct{\myquatP}{\myquatQ}}\myquatTmp % This works

    \def\myquatQrot{\quaternionproduct{\myquatTmp}{\myquatInvP}}\myquatQrot % This does not
    % \myquatQrot should be in the form (0, x, y, z)
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % [...] Draws the rotated points
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You aren`t actually doing anything with the results of the calculations, you are just writing them into your document.  You'll need to store them in macro(s) and then use them in the transformation command.

Comment: Yes, I know, I omitted the code to draw for brevity. The point is that if the second product generates an error, I don't even have a coordinate to use in tikz.

Comment: Your `\quaterniontoxyz` doesn't produce the components in a form that is usable by another function. Each component is calculated and written out to the document, and then the macro `\pgfmathresult` is overwritten. So a function wanting to use those values won't have access to them.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks for your comment, it enlightened me!
I fixed the `\quaterniontoxyz` function like this:
`\newcommand{\quaterniontoxyz}[2] {\pgfmathsetmacro\q@x{{#2}[1]}\pgfmathsetmacro\q@y{{#2}[2]}\pgfmathsetmacro\q@z{{#2}[3]}\edef#1{\q@x,\q@y,\q@z}}`
And I did a similar thing for `\quaternionproduct`